# Debugging remote event receiver - no context token

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, debugging, remote-event-receiver, azure-service-bus

I am trying to use the MS supplied [BasicDataOperations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Use-event-8b5a551f/) provider hosted app to play around with and learn about remote event receivers.

I was following the instructions [from this blog post by Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html) to deploy the app to a SharePoint Online site, and deploy the remote event receiver web to an Azure website.  I've also set up an Azure Service Bus to do the redirection to my computer so I can debug the code.

When I try to debug, everything starts up normally, the app gets deployed to the SharePoint site, and when I add a list item through the app, my breakpoint gets hit.  However, I am also getting a `GetContextTokenError`.  The error message is:

> The endpoint address
>   'https://my-servicebus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/DL-TAG365/dcristy/obj/4fd86c25-6149-4455-adc6-fb3f20cfcb04/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc'
>   does not match the app's endpoint 'my-azure-site.azurewebsites.net'.

I'm not sure where to go to specify/change the app's endpoint.  Is that happening because I registered the app on AppRegNew.aspx using the Azure site URL?

My app manifest looks like this:

```
  <Properties>
    <Title>BasicDataOperations</Title>
    <StartPage>https://my-azure-site.azurewebsites.net/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
    <!--<StartPage>~appWebUrl/Lists/List1</StartPage>-->
    <InstalledEventEndpoint>~remoteAppUrl/AppEventReceiver.svc</InstalledEventEndpoint>
  </Properties>
```

and as far as I'm aware, using the `~remoteAppUrl` token in the event endpoint is what's somehow connecting the events through the service bus back to my computer.  That's also what I'm using in the event receiver declaration:

```
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>RemoteEventReceiver1ItemAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Url>~remoteAppUrl/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc</Url>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
```

And I'm not even worried about the AppEventReceiever.svc right now, I just want to get everything  working with the RemoteEventReceiver1.svc.  Without the token, the BasicDataOperations code doesn't run (they check for a valid context token before doing anything), and even if I wrote some code that would run, I'm sure I probably need that context token for something, right?

So how do I set it up so that I get a valid context token while debugging?

Comment: Did you make the debug work? Just got the same issue here and would like to know before hunting a solution.

Comment: Luciano, I did not get it working.  It was just playing around learning, not related to any specific project, so when something more urgent came along I abandoned it.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. So, I will be investigating a solution form now.

Answer (score 1):

In your **AppManifest.xml**

It should be like this:

```
<Properties>
    <Title>BasicDataOperations</Title>
    <StartPage>https://my-azure-site.azurewebsites.net/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
    <!--<StartPage>~appWebUrl/Lists/List1</StartPage>-->
    <InstalledEventEndpoint>https://my-azure-site.azurewebsites.net/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc</InstalledEventEndpoint>
  </Properties>
```

And your Remote Event Receiver's **Element.xml** should be like this:

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>RemoteEventReceiver1ItemAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Url>https://my-azure-site.azurewebsites.net/Services/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc</Url>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
```

Comment: ~remoteAppUrl is automatically replaced by Visual Studio at deployment, so there is no need to hard-code it.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and resolved it by updating `ClientId` as `*` in `AppMenifest.xml` file. Please try this if anyone facing the issue.